# Why would an int be formatted as %#X in a printf function?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

I'm debugging some code (not written by myself) and have an int `index` being printed with `%#X` in a printf function.  From my understanding `%#X` is an uppercase *unsigned* hexadecimal integer.

Is this ok/is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#` conversion specifier indicates that the *alternative* conversion should be used.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf):

> In the alternative implementation `0x` or `0X` is prefixed to results if
> the converted value is nonzero.

So, it would seem this is intentional by the author.

If you are asking instead about the *unsigned* part of this, `%X` is *always* unsigned.  If you have a signed value and you want your hex value to be prefixed with a negative sign for negatives, you will have to roll your own.

Otherwise, it's quite fine to have a signed value as input -- it will simply be reinterpreted as unsigned.  Unless this is the bug you've identified in your program! ;)

Comment: Re “it's quite fine to have a signed value as input”: C 2018 7.21.6.1 9 says the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

> From my understanding %#X is an uppercase unsigned hexadecimal integer.

This is correct, per the C standard, the argument corresponding to `%#X` should be an `unsigned int`, and the behavior of passing an `int` is technically not defined by the C standard, per C 2018 7.21.6.1 8 (which says `X` is for `unsigned int`) and 9 (“If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.”)

In practice, few, if any C implementations will complain about this or behave other than to, in effect, reinterpret the bits of the `int` as an `unsigned int`.

> Is this ok/is there any way around this?

To make the code pedantically correct, cast the argument to `unsigned int`.

Comment: The code is testing to verify that ``index`` meets a minimum length requirement, and in cases where it doesn't, prints an error message and the index, formatted as ``%#X``.  So I assume that index was defined as ``int`` in the (probably rare) case that the index is a negative value.  But this would mean that having a signed value as input for ``%#X`` is undefined as you said... Sorry, probably my fault for not putting enough information in the question description, I was told the code I'm working with is sensitive so I didn't want to post too much info.

Answer (score 0):

The `#` combined with `X` format will print `0X` before printing your `index` value in uppercase hexadecimal format.
It looks totally okay and without further explanation, we couldn't give you a "way around this".

Comment: Re “It looks totally okay”: C 2018 7.21.6.1 9 says the behavior is undefined. Re “we couldn't give you a "way around this"”: Casting to `unsigned int` is a way around it.